# how can i check if an array value is available inside an array of stdclass object

Tags: php, arrays, object

I'm trying to check if the of an id is available inside this array of std objects, i do not want to loop through the array as it will not display the correct information. My code is as follows:

> ```
>   Array(
>     [0] => stdClass Object
>         (
>             [name] => My Name
>             [id] => 1234567890
>         )
>     [1] => stdClass Object
>         (
>             [name] => Other User Name
>             [id] => 987654321
>         )
>   )
> ```

I tried using in_array method and it doesnt find the id key and value.

Thank you 
D~~

Comment: What's wrong with loops? Why won't looping give you the correct data?

Comment: You will, in one way or another, have to loop through the array to find an entry by id value. Maybe you can explain "... as it will not display the correct information" a bit better.

Comment: What do you mean you do not want to loop through the array? As far as I can tell it will be your only solution

Comment: Could you reorganize the array to use the IDs as indices?

Comment: Sorry guys, i used the loop in a separate function that stores all the id's inside an array and it worked like a charm..my bad..thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to loop the array to perform a check on an attribute of the objects inside the array. Write a function that will return your desired value like (pseudo-code):

```
function returnObjectForId($idToMatch){
    foreach ($array as $i => $object) {
        if($object->id == $idToMatch){
            return $object
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, been a while since I've programmed PHP :)

Answer (score 0):

With the help of Anzeo's answer I upgraded it a bit to work with other properties and to be used in conditional statements, take a peek:

```
function my_in_array($needle, $haystack = array(), $property){
    foreach ($haystack as $object) {
        if($object->$property == $needle){
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
foreach($foo as $bar) {
    if(!my_in_array($bar, $arrWithObjects, 'id')) {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Hope this is useful for someone else

EDIT

I also found a nice trick to convert the object's properties into an array, that might help in some situations.

```
foreach($arrWithObjects as $obj) {
    $objProps = get_object_vars($obj);
    if(in_array('My Name', $objProps)) {
        //do something
    }
}
```